# How to give an element an id

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code

```js
var inter = [];
const changeColor = (evt) => {
  if (evt.currentTarget.classList.contains("is-active")) {
    evt.currentTarget.classList.remove("is-active");
  } else {
    evt.currentTarget.classList.add("is-active");
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('is-active');
    inter = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      inter.push(elements[i].innerHTML)
    }
    alert(inter);
  }
};
const EL_tagger1010_children = document.querySelectorAll(".tagger1010 span");
EL_tagger1010_children.forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("click", changeColor));
```

```css
.tagger1010 span {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  background: #D0E8E4;
  border-radius: 18px;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0 4px 8px 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  border: 1px solid BBD0CD;
}

.tagger1010 span.is-active {
  background-color: #008fde;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tagger1010 span:hover {
  background-color: #008fde;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="tagger1010">
  <span>Google</span>
  <span>Microsoft</span>
  <span>Facebook</span>
  <span>LinkedIn</span>
</div>

<div class="as-console-wrapper"></div>
<div class="as-console"></div>

<div class="as-console-wrapper">
  <div class="as-console">

  </div>
</div>
```

This code does what I want it to do for now, but I would like to create an element that has an id that stores the value of the "inter" array in the following code. I have never before seen an instance where a single variable has an id that can be referenced elsewhere. So I was wondering if I can put the value of the "inter" array in a div element, or if I can just assign an id to the inter array itself?

Comment: Why do you need an id?

Comment: I am writing code to add to a no-code tool (bubble.io), and I need to pull the value of the variable to use elsewhere - one of the only ways to do it in that tool is to have an id.

Comment: You in reality are just reinventing a radio button list.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the DOM id feature:

```
document.getElementById("demo").id = "newid";
```

Reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_id.asp

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign the id of an HTML node to a JS array, but you can put the contents of an array in to a div and assign an id to that div. You can create the div on the fly in the JS code, or put it directly into your HTML and just fill in the array values and assign the id. Following an example of how to create a div in JavaScript, set an id on it and put the array values into it one by one:

```js
var arr = ["some", "array", "values"];
div = document.createElement("div"); // create a new div
div.id = "someid"; // set the id of the div
for (var item of arr) {
  div.innerHTML += "<p>" + item + "</p>"; // put each array item into a separate paragraph in the div
}
document.body.appendChild(div); // append the div with the paragraphs to the document body
```

```css
#someid {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>The array values are displayed below.</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving you another option of just using radio button list to render the selectable list. To get the selection, you just read the form field value.

```css
[name="rb-site"] {
  display: none;
}

[name="rb-site"] label {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  background: #D0E8E4;
  border-radius: 18px;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0 4px 8px 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  border: 1px solid BBD0CD;
}

[name="rb-site"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #008fde;
  color: #ffffff;
}

[name="rb-site"] + label:hover {
  background-color: #008fde;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="tagger1010">
  <input type="radio" value="google" id="rb-google" name="rb-site">
  <label for="rb-google">Google</label>
<input type="radio" value="microsoft" id="rb-microsoft" name="rb-site">
  <label for="rb-microsoft">Microsoft</label>
<input type="radio" value="Facebook" id="rb-facebook" name="rb-site">
  <label for="rb-facebook">Facebook</label>
<input type="radio" value="LinkedIn" id="rb-linkedin" name="rb-site">
  <label for="rb-linkedin">LinkedIn</label>
</div>
```

So when you want to get the selected radio button and read the variable.

```
document.querySelctor('name="rb-site"]:checked').value
```

It is more HTML, but less JavaScript.